# What's the name of an outward-linebased circle patter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, style-identification

I need to reproduce this figure, ideally using SVG so I tried looking for online tutorials to re-create it using illustrator but I couldn't find anything remotely matching my needs, most likely because I didn't really know what to look for as a the name of this thread shows ... I don't really know what this kind of figure would be called.

Is there a general name ? If not, how would you describe it to help find an appropriate tutorial or maybe even point me directly to one describing the process to design something similar ?

[image: Outward extending lines]

Comment: Not everything has a specific name.

Comment: I think I poorly worded my question. AAGD answered it properly, I was really more after any way to refer to this kind of pattern than a precise name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point could be `radial line pattern`.